# Tomcat Website Returning Blank Pages

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, web-deployment, catalina.out

I am have been grinding since last week trying to deploy a tomcat7 website.  I am using JDK8.

I check my catalina out file and this is the only error that I see.  Maybe it has something to do with JDK8 being used?

```
Jul 24, 2015 4:17:03 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
```

Lastly, when I go to my url it is receiving traffic but not rendering anything.  We have Spring security built in so when you hit a secure page it actually redirects to the login page.  However when it goes to a page without security or to the login page you get a “400 Bad Request” message in chrome and "401 Unauthorized" which is followed by a "404 Not Found" in firefox.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was a silly error on my part.  I was using Spring Profiles for my Spring component that extended the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.  Since I was not setting the spring profile this class was being ignored, thus never creating beans for the ViewResolver or my Apache Tiles Configurer.